# Using open() to create a file in C

Tags: c

This is the first time I am using `open()` from:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

I am trying to create two files:

```
int fd;
int fd2;
char *tmpname = "./TMPFILE";
printf( "Temporary file created\n ");
char *tmpname2 = "./TMPFILE2";
printf( "Temporary file two created\n ");
fd = open(tmpname, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
fd2 = open(tmpname2, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
```

I am trying to create the files in the current working directory that can be written and appended to.

This compiles and runs, but my concern is that when I check my directory to see if the files were created, they aren't listed.

My question is does `open()` only make temporary files that are removed after the program runs or did I screw something up?

Comment: u did do "ls -ail" - ie force the inclusion of files starting with "."

Comment: @pm100 Yeah, I tried that and nothing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When creating a file, you need a third parameter to open (the `mode`). If you don't do this, unpredictable things happen.

Also, if you want to create a file if it's not there, you will need `O_CREAT` or'd in, i.e.

```
fd = open(tmpname, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0644);
```

`O_CREAT` (roughly speaking) creates the file if it isn't present.

From the man page:

```
NAME
       open, creat - open and possibly create a file or device

SYNOPSIS
       #include 
       #include 
       #include 

       int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
       int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

       int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);

...
       O_CREAT
              If the file does not exist it will be created.  The owner (user ID) of
              the  file  is  set to the effective user ID of the process.  The group
              ownership (group ID) is set either to the effective group  ID  of  the
              process  or  to  the  group  ID  of the parent directory (depending on
              filesystem type and mount options, and the mode of the  parent  direc‐
              tory,  see  the  mount  options  bsdgroups and sysvgroups described in
              mount(8)).

              mode specifies the permissions to use in case a new file  is  created.
              This  argument must be supplied when O_CREAT is specified in flags; if
              O_CREAT is not specified, then mode is ignored.  The effective permis‐
              sions  are  modified by the process's umask in the usual way: The per‐
              missions of the created file are (mode & ~umask).  Note that this mode
              applies  only to future accesses of the newly created file; the open()
              call that creates a read-only file may well return a  read/write  file
              descriptor.
```

Comment: @abligh Well, what do you know, I am an idiot haha. Thank you for your help. Next time I will just take the advice and read the manual.

Comment: Where did 0644 come from? I could not find this mode in the man pages

Comment: @PyWalker2797 it is an octal expression (leading `0`) of the unix file mode. See e.g. the `chmod` manpage. `0644` means the owner can read+write (4+2=`6`), the group can read (`4`), and others can read (`4`).

Comment: @PyWalker2797 you can also use http://permissions-calculator.org/ to calculate the proper code for your permission level

Comment: Is there any reason to have both the `O_WRONLY` flag and `O_APPEND`?

Comment: Ah, I need to read the manual as well haha:
`The argument flags must include one of the following access modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR.  These request opening the file read-only, write-only, or read/write, respectively.`