# system call to write and read from a file

Tags: c, undeclared-identifier

I want to test the system call of `read` and `write`

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    fd = open("/Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo/C/APUE/3.File_IO/test", O_RDWR);
    write(fd, "Test the first line",20);
}
```

The cc reports:

```
In [29]: !cc write_test.c                                                                                         
write_test.c:6:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'fd'
    fd = open("/Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo/C/APUE/3.File_IO/test", O_RDWR);
    ^
write_test.c:7:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'fd'
    write(fd, "Test the first line",20)
          ^
2 errors generated.
```

I have some python basics, but have no idea how to get the code done.

Comment: **fd** is not declared as said so it produces 2 errors since it has 2 usages

Comment: When attempting to use a new language for the first time, getting to know it first is usually good (instead of just guessing and hoping for the best). Just like when learning a new spoken and written language. So please get a couple of beginners book, read some tutorials, or take a class or two, before continuing.

Comment: yes,  I am taking APUE. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: APUE is a book about programming in a Unix-like environment, but it's not a *language* book. It requires you to already know C.

Comment: Also, if you're reading APUE then it should have taught you to check for errors, and clean up your resources (IIRC, long time since I read it). You should check that [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) succeed. And you should [`close`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html) the file when you're done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare what type `fd` is. What type is that? Check the reference of [`open()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open), which mentions:

> int open(const char *path, int oflag, ... );

You can see that the return type is `int`. As a result, the variable that should be assigned the return value of that function should also be of the same type.

So change:

```
fd = open("/Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo/C/APUE/3.File_IO/test", O_RDWR);
```

to this:

```
int fd = open("/Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo/C/APUE/3.File_IO/test", O_RDWR);
```

---

PS: If the file doesn't exist, then you will need to do:

```
int fd = open("/Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo/C/APUE/3.File_IO/test", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);
```

Read more in [Using open() to create a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466715/using-open-to-create-a-file-in-c).

Comment: thanks for your kind tutorial, it works but the message does not write into when `cat test` to check.

Comment: @avirate Have you checked if the file could be opened? `open()` won't create a new file when you don't pass `O_CREAT`.

Comment: @avirate if the file doesn't exist in the first place, you need to use the `O_CREAT` as well, and a creation mode as the 3rd parameter, as @Ctx mentioned. Then if you `sudo cat <yourFile>` it will work.  But maybe then you would like to append, but that's up to you. Read more in [Using open to create files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466715/using-open-to-create-a-file-in-c). However, I **strongly suggest you** to take a step back and learn some basic C first, before diving into APUE. Edit: Swordfish is right and faster than me! :)

Comment: If you use O_CREAT, you additionally should provide a creation mode as third parameter, i.e. `0600`

Comment: thank you all for the kindness and patience, I feel and cannot say anything.